# -I flag in the makefile does not result in a header file being found (gtest/gtest.h)

Tags: c++, makefile

Previously I was struggling with creating a makefile in root directory that would deal with source files being in `src` folder and headers in `include` folder. Following this I wanted to add another folder `tests` where I would keep .cpp files with tests. Unfortunately I have problems with this.

The folder structure is:

```
.
|__makefile
|
|__/src
|  |
|  |__[regular .cpp files]
|
|__/include
|  |
|  |__[.h files]
|  |
|  |__/gtest
|     |
|     |__gtest.h
|
|__/tests
   |
   |__test_factorial.cpp
```

./tests/test_factorial.cpp:

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "factorial.h"

// some tests
```

makefile:

```
CC = g++

CFLAGS = -Wall

INCLUDES = -I./include

LIBS = -lgtest -lpthread

SOURCEDIR = ./src/
SRCS = $(shell find ./src/ -name '*.cpp')
SRCS += $(shell find ./tests/ -name '*.cpp')

.PHONY: clean depend

SRCS := $(filter-out ./tests/main_tests.cpp, $(SRCS))
OBJS = $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)
OBJS := $(OBJS:./src%=.%)

release: $(OBJS)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o app $(OBJS) $(LIBS)

VPATH = ./src:./tests

%.o: ./src/%.cpp
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c ./src/$*.cpp

%.o: ./tests/%.cpp
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c ./tests/$*.cpp

depend: .depend

.depend: $(SRCS)
        rm -f ./.depend
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -MM $^ > ./.depend;

include .depend
```

When I execute `make` from the root directory all the files from /src compile fine (I end up having object files in the root directory for them) but I get an error for .cpp file from /tests directory:

```
g++    -c -o tests/test_factorial.o tests/test_factorial.cpp
tests/test_factorial.cpp:1:25: fatal error: gtest/gtest.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'tests/test_factorial.o' failed
make: *** [tests/test_factorial.o] Error 1
```

What might be important, the .depend file seems to have it all right:

```
test_factorial.o: tests/test_factorial.cpp include/gtest/gtest.h \
 include/factorial.h
```

What is wrong with the makefile?

**EDIT**

I believe this fragment of the error:

```
<builtin>: recipe for target 'tests/test_factorial.o' failed
```

suggests that something is wrong in this part of the makefile:

```
%.o: ./src/%.cpp
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c ./src/$*.cpp

%.o: ./tests/%.cpp
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c ./tests/$*.cpp
```

Why it's trying to do `./tests/test_factorial.o` rather than `./test_factorial.o`? Let me underline again that object files for ./src/*.cpp files end up in root directory, i.e. `./*.o`, not `./src/*.o`.

Comment: The title is flatly wrong, the actual build output shows no `-I` option being passed to `g++`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your makefile is building

```
tests/test_factorial.o
```

from

```
tests/test_factorial.cpp
```

and that doesn't match the rule

```
%.o: ./tests/%.cpp
```

So it is instead using a builtin rule.  (As an aside, the convention is to build c++ files using `$(CXX)` and `$(CXXFLAGS)` not `$(CC)`).

Try a rule pattern of

```
./tests/%.o: ./tests/%.cpp
```

---

The reason that your Makefile uses the name `tests/test_factorial.o` is because

```
OBJS = $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)
```

which (it should be obvious) makes the path to the `.o` file the same as the path to the `.cpp`.

You have a subsequent rule stripping the path `src/`

```
OBJS := $(OBJS:./src%=.%)
```

and no similar rule for `tests/`

Comment: Ah! Yes... A simple omission... I just added OBJS := $(OBJS:./tests%=.%) and it's all working. Thank you.